# How to read tagged users from Facebook comments - Facebook API

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-webhooks

I'm building a facebook comment bot that should interact with users via comments. Users should tag their friend to participate in the interaction with the bot.

I've submitted app to review for `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` and it has passed. After that I have subscribed to `feed` webhook under the `page` tab in webhook section of facebook developer dashboard.

Here is the sample of the JSON returned feed webhook.

```
{
"entry": [
    {
        "changes": [
            {
                "field": "feed",
                "value": {
                    "from": {
                        "id": "123123123123",
                        "name": "Tagger"
                    },
                    "item": "comment",
                    "comment_id": "123123123123_123123123833",
                    "post_id": "579082309230135_598902880581411",
                    "verb": "add",
                    "parent_id": "123123123123_123123123123",
                    "created_time": 1551120353,
                    "post": {
                        "type": "status",
                        "updated_time": "2019-02-23T18:44:53+0000",
                        "promotion_status": "inactive",
                        "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/mypage/posts/123123123123",
                        "id": "123123123123_5123123123123123",
                        "status_type": "mobile_status_update",
                        "is_published": true
                    },
                    "message": "Taggedd user"
                }
            }
        ],
        "id": "1231231231313",
        "time": 123123123123
    }
],
"object": "page"}
```

**Note:** I have changed data to ensure privacy and this is just an sample.

**So question is:** How to read tagged users from Facebook comments?

Comment: Just so you know. You are not allowed to incentive users to tag their friends.

Comment: @WizKid Hey didn't know that, I have made clear to Facebook review team how will the app be used but they haven't said anything against that.

Comment: Rule 4.4 in https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Okay, but if the user tags his friend on his own is there way to read the tag from comment?

Comment: What would you do with that information?

Comment: I haven't decided yet, talking hypothetically is it possible to do that?

Comment: Depends on what you are going to do with the data

Comment: Anything that's within facebook terms and regulations

Comment: So what specific thing is that?

Comment: I haven't decided yet

Comment: Then decide and come back here when you know what you would use it for

Comment: To be honest it's for the client who want's to do giveaways with it :)

Comment: I figured :P Which is not allowed.

Comment: Greedy facebook :p

Comment: As a user I'm very happy that pages can't make people spam for them